# Password stopped working after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, password-recovery

We have been using ubuntu for over two years. Every time we download an upgrade, our password has always kept working. After downloading 11.10, The password quit working. We went to the community to get answers to retrieve. We followed the prompting to reset password and ran into problems. We made it to where it says to change the RW to RO. It gave us four lines for 11.10. All four did not have a RW at the end of the line. Then we got a message stating daemon had died. We can use the computer but cannot update or change anything without the password. Can anyone help us? We have a Compaq Presario SR2170NX with a new hard drive. We had Vista on the old hard drive and it died. When we bought new, we went with ubuntu and it works great for our needs except for iTunes and this problem.

Comment: "*We made it to where it says to change the RW to RO.*" What instructions say to change `rw` to `ro`? [These instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword#The_Other_Way) say to change `ro` to `rw`, which is just the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but do you mean the password that is requested when you try to, eg, update packages?

I think you have tried to follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

Did 'The Standard Way' not work?

Can you edit your original question with information as to what went wrong? It shouldn't be necessary for you to need to be editing grub config (which is what you ended up doing, by the sound of it, when changing ro to rw etc).

Comment: Thanks, Did the /Lost Password. Have been able to change root password. But unable to authenticate/upgrade anything. Got an error message saying "daemon has died"?